# How to insert 6,500,000 records into a table that contains 126 columns?

Tags: c#, database, .net-6.0

My application is running on .NET Core 6. I am using the `BulkExtensions` library which allows me to enter 2,400,000 records, then I get this message

> The node was low on resource: memory container fifi-web using 36045744Ki, which exceeds its request of 0

and the server restarts.

The records are obtained from a .cat file that is traversed line by line to obtain each parameter and the method I am using is the following:

```cs
public void InsertCatsFromFileWithBulkInsertAzure(List<string> lines, string name, string username, Guid id, DateTime? dateCat)
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    long pendingLines = 0;
    var executionStrategy = _context.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy();            

    executionStrategy.Execute(
        () =>
        {
            List<Cat> data = new List<Cat>();

            for (var i = 1; i < lines.Count; i++)
            {                        
                try
                {                       
                    Cat parsedCat = ParseCat(i, lines);
                    parsedCat.CatGeneralId = id;
                    parsedCat.Date = now;
                    parsedCat.DateCat = dateCat;
                    data.Add(parsedCat);
                    pendingLines++;

                    if (pendingLines == 150000)
                    {
                        _context.Cats.AddRange(data);
                        _context.BulkSaveChanges();
                        data.Clear();
                        pendingLines = 0;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var line = new Cat
                    {
                        Type = lines[i].Substring(0, 2),
                        CadastralParcel = lines[i].Substring(30, 14),
                    };
                    Console.WriteLine($"Se presento un error con el codigo CadastralParcel: {line.CadastralParcel}, Type: {line.Type} en la linea: {i}. mensaje de error: {ex.Message}");
                }
            }
            _context.Cats.AddRange(data);
            _context.BulkSaveChanges();
        });
}
```

We tried the process of uploading a csv file into the database but it gave the same error and takes longer than expected.

Comment: Have you tried with smaller batch sizes (2m, 1.5m, 1m, 100k etc. rows at a time)? You might find a stable "threshold" you can use, then only batch upsert that many records at a time.

Comment: We have already tried this part varying the quantity in 5.000, 20.000, 50.000, 100.000 records and with the one we were able to insert more data (2.400.000) was with the one of 50.000 ... with the other batches we did not manage to go beyond 1.600.000 and we also got the same error.

Comment: use SQL bulk copy

Comment: https://entityframework-extensions.net/improve-bulk-savechanges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear you context after save changes. The change tracker keeps a copy of your entities.

```
_context.ChangeTracker.Clear();
```